# how do I calculate the width of a center div

Tags: html, css

I have three `div`s stacked horizontally -> left, center and right.

Left and right are fixed width at `250px`. I want the center `div` to have the max possible width.  How do I do this?

Once this `div` is set to max possible, I will be setting the `div` inside it to `margin:0 auto;` to center align it.

Comment: Where is your code?  Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: Thank you everybody. This was pretty straight forward. I'm a newbie learner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do any calculations to achieve this.  You can do it by some clever structuring of your HTML and a little bit of CSS!

Try this - View the Example in action, here: http://jsfiddle.net/zfg6m/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
        This is my left column!
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        This is my right column!
    </div>
    <div class="center-col">
        This is my center column
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left-col {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;   
}

.right-col {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;  
}

.center-col {
  background-color: blue;   
}
```

What's happening with this code?  Well you're floating the two columns placed above the center column.  Since the two floats are not cleared, they collapse and form space for your center column to fill 100% width of the area.  This allows your center column to remain in between the two column, but stay dynamic in width.

Answer (score 2):

the order in which you define the elements is important here. you need to create the left/right divs *before* you create the center div in the html. this is because the browser needs to draw the left/right sides of your layout before knowing how much space is available for the center div.

here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/vtvxb/

Answer (score 1):

http://dabblet.com/gist/3743636
'Overflow: hidden' will save you here. Although the source order has to be as follows:

```
<div class="left"></div>

<div class="right"></div>

<div class="center"></div>
```

And you don't(shouldn't) need to set a margin for the center div; 'overlflow: hidden' is to clear floats, more on that here: http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ (recommended reading).

Answer (score 0):

The width will be the `page body width` - `500px`.